# Do HashMap values need to be immutable?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I understand that keys in a HashMap need to be immutable, or at least ensure that their hash code (`hashCode()`) will not change or conflict with another object with different state.

However, do the values stored in HashMap need to be the same as above*? Why or why not?

* The idea is to be able to mutate the values (such as calling setters on it) without affecting the ability to retrieve them later from the HashMap using immutable keys. If values are mutated, **can that break their association to the keys?**

*My question is mainly concerning Java, however, answers for other languages are welcome.*

Comment: Since there are many answers essentially saying the same thing, I will let voting decide (over time) which answer should be marked accepted.

Answer (score 2):

No. In general the characteristics of a hash map data structure do not depend upon the value.  Having keys be immutable is important because the underlying data structures are built using  the hash of the key at the time of insertion.  The underlying data structures are designed to provide certain properties (relatively fast look up, fast removal, fast removal, etc...) all based upon this hash.  If this hash were to change then the data structure with these nice properties based upon a hash which has changed will be invalidated.  If you need to "modify" a key one general approach is to remove the old key and re-insert the new key.

Answer (score 2):

The values of a HashMap do not need to be immutable. The map generally does not care what happens to the value (unless it is a ConcurrentHashMap), only where in memory that value is located.

In the case of ConcurrentHashMap, the mutability of the value is not affected, but it would be overly broad to say that the map does not "care" what happens to the value. Even though concurrency is allowed on updates to the map, the values that the map points to can be manipulated with no effect to the the immutable keys.

Comment: Can you clarify your "unless it is a ConcurrentHashMap" statement?  What is your justification for ConcurrentHashMap treating values differently than other types of Maps?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap does not change the mutability of the values of a hashmap, but saying that it does not "care" would be overly broad, given that concurrency is controlled for updates.

Comment: Kindly expand your answer about ConcurrentHashMap (just copy your comment above into the answer, and elaborate a bit more). Does updating values stored in a ConcurrentHashMap potentially break their association with immutable keys in the same map?

Comment: @uberchris - Your clarification still does not make your point clear. I would suggest removing the "care" terminology and being more specific. I'm not sure why `ConcurrentHashMap` would have different characteristics with respect to the values it stores.

Answer (score 2):

RE: *If values are mutated, can that break their association to the keys?*.

No.

A Map returns an object reference given a key.  That key will alway point to the same object reference.  Changing the object in some way (i.e. changing its instance variables) will **not** affect the ability to retrieve that object.

Comment: Great. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

No values do not *need* to be immutable, but can be very good practice.  This of course depends on your use-case.

Here is a use-case where immutability was important:  I recently ran into a bug because of this.  An entry was put in a cache (backed by a HashMap).  Later, this entry was retrieved and altered.  Because the value was mutable (i.e. allowed changes), the next retrieve of the entry still had the edits made by the previous retriever.  This was a problem because in my use case, the cache data was not supposed to change.

Consider this example:

```
    Class Foo {
       int a;
       public Foo(int a) { this.a = a; }
       public void setA(int x) { this.a = a; }
    }

    Map<String, Foo> data = getFooMap();
    Foo foo = new Foo(17);
    data.put("entry1", foo);

    Foo entry1 = map.get("entry1);
    System.out.println(entry1.a);   // prints "17"

    entry1.setA(18); 

...

   Foo entry1 = map.get("entry1);
   System.out.println(entry1.a);   // prints "18"
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the "good practice" statement in the general case.  It depends upon your use case of course but in general being able to modify values is an important characteristic of maps.

Comment: Fair point.  That occurred to me as I was writing the example.  I have made note of that in my answer.

Comment: Your use case requires values to remain unchanged, while they are in fact changing. My question was whether values can be changed without affecting the ability to retrieve them later from the HashMap (assuming keys to retrieve them are intact). Or, does changing values break their association with keys in a HashMap?

Comment: OK, That is a good clarification.  Can you please add that statement (My question was whether values can be changed without affecting the ability to retrieve them later from the HashMap) to the question.  I will submit an answer that addresses it.

Comment: New answer submitted.  I just did not want to clutter this one up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

not really. having a mutable key will bring significant issues but what values you put it does not really matter. If the value is an mutable object and one modifies it, then of course the value is updated as well (but that's nothing to do with Hashmap).