# Does Java HashMap require values to be immutable?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am learning Java `HashMap` Class(Key,Value) and found why `Key` needs to be `Immutable` as if it is changed later after being added to hash it maybe in wrong bucket.

But what about `Value` ? Does it needs to be `Immutable` too ?

This came to me as I recently encountered a problem where I got weird behaviour(keys that were not in map returned true on `containsKey()`) when I was using `AtomicInteger` with `addAndGet()` method to change value.

Then I switched to putting `new Integer()` whenever I needed to change the value corresponding to a key and that resolved the problem.

**EDIT**

Well this was just to ask for Immutable but here's the code :

`

```
HashMap<Long , PreparedStatement> hash_map= new HashMap<Long, PreparedStatement>(); 
HashMap<Long , Integer> hash_map_count = new HashMap<Long , Integer>();

//some code here , lets say phone value comes to a function and function contains this code

 if(hash_map.containsKey( phone)) // present
        {
            ps_insert = (PreparedStatement)hash_map.get( phone);
            count_temp = hash_map_count.get( phone);

            if(count_temp == null)
            {
                System.out.println("************"+ phone);

            }

            count_temp.addAndGet(1); //no need to re-insert into map as value changed by +1 here.
        System.out.println("count : "+count_temp.get()); // 

    }
    else
    {
        ps_temp = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into T_"+ phone+" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        hash_map.put( phone,ps_temp);
        count_temp = new AtomicInteger(1);
        hash_map_count.put( phone, count_temp);
        ps_insert = ps_temp;
        System.out.println("new phone :"+ phone+" count :"+count_temp.get());
    }
```

The problem was the ****** got printed with phone (i.e. I got null) in count_temp.How is that possible when I have inserted a `AtomicInteger` for phone
Then I checked and found that phone was never inserted to hash map and still `containsKey()` returned true for it.

Now can anybody explain why that might have happened and why changing to `Integer()` and inserting `new Integer(changed value)` corrected it ?

Comment: Please show the specific code that caused the problem. The value doesn't have to be immutable.

Comment: There is as such no requirement that `value` also needs to be immutable along with the `key`

Comment: @Eran i meant `value` that time. typo was there

Comment: I'm still waiting to see the code that causes the problem like Eran asked initially.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do HashMap values need to be immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836168/do-hashmap-values-need-to-be-immutable)

Comment: @Eran

Posted the code , unable to edit it properly

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. How could something be present in a new Map you just created?

Comment: When we asked for the example we meant a working example that we can read and build if needed. I have no idea what value phone is equal to and see nowhere that you have actually added any values to the maps, so how can I/we answer your question?

Comment: @JBNizet : Sir this code is a part of a very large program.

Let me explain, the phone is passed as argument to a function which contains this code.

When a phone that is not present i.e. `containsKey()` return false I add a new `AtomicInteger` as value in hash_map_count with phone as key.

And the problem is posted below the code.

Thanks

Comment: @Tuxxy_Thang :
Sir whole code is very long and will be rather problematic to post .
I add the values to map in else case i.e when map dosen't contain a phone(as key) I add the phone with a `AtomicInteger` in `hash_map_count`

Comment: Apologies ide spazzed when I copied it in fast and di not see the error properly. There is a single quote after the last brace in your code example.

Comment: Well, somehow, you inserted a key into hash_map but didn't inserty it into hash_map_count (or removed it later). Unless you provide code reproducing the problem, we can't help. BTW, the above code is far from being real: you can't insert an AtomicInteger into a Map<Long, Integer>.

Comment: Is the code you posted the only code that modifies the two maps?

Comment: @JBNizet : The only portion of code where I insert lies in the `else` portion and there I put in both maps and I don't change the value thereafter that is sure ,  just count_temp.get() was used once.

Thanks for your help , posting whole code is not possible.

Comment: @Eran : Yes and hash map's were never touched after just count_temp.get() was used once.

Comment: I just looped your snippet 2 times witht he same value for phone and the first time it inserted it and the second time it confirmed the existence of the key with a count of 2.

Comment: BTW, I had to modify your hash_map_count to HashMap<Long , AtomicInteger> hash_map_count = new HashMap<>(); as you are adding AtomicInteger values not Integer values.

Comment: @Tuxxy_Thang :
Yes sorry for posting the hash map I am currently using earlier I used this only : `HashMap<Long , AtomicInteger> hash_map_count = new HashMap<Long , AtomicInteger>()` and yes it will work fine some small cases , and will fail at just one or 2 cases when large no of phone's are thrown at it .

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Well sorry but without seeing the code around the problem I canot be of more help. BTW, you do not need to state type in your maps twice.  After HashMap<T, T> has been declared any instantiation can be shortened to new HashMap<>(), where Java will take the type inference from the declaration so it is enough for you to do HashMap<Long , AtomicInteger> hash_map_count = new HashMap<>().

Comment: Hmm, just cycled your snippet through 2,000,000 new phone numbers and none were flagged as already existing. So your code, such as it is, works and doe not appear to be affected by large volumes of phone numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Value of a Map can be modified.

Also a key can be modified. Key needs to follow the condition that `equals()` and `hashCode()` before and after a modification will give the same results (with same input value in case of `equals()`). Also if keys can be modified generally they are unmodifiable.

To better show why a key can be modifiable I add a little explanation on how HashMap works and how a ModifiableKey can be coded.

**How works an HashMap:**

Internally an HashMap uses an array of Entry where Entry is a tern (Key, Value, Entry).

```
table

0 --> {K, V, E} --> {K, V, null}
1 --> {k, V, null}
2
3
4 --> {K, V, null}
5
```

Here is the code of get()

```
 public V get(Object key) {
     if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
     int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
             return e.value;
     }
     return null;
 }
```

As you can see first is calculated the `hashCode` of the key. The hashCode is then used to find an index in the table. If the a Key exists in the map is possible to reach it looping through the linked list of Entry elements at that position.
To check if that key exists the equals() method is used (inside the for loop).

**How to build a modifiable key usable in a map**

So suppose to have the following class that you like to use as key.

```
public class ModifiableKey {
    private String unmodifiablePart;
    private String modifiablePart;


    public ModifiableKey(String unmodifiablePart) {
        this.unmodifiablePart = unmodifiablePart;
    }

    public String getUnmodifiablePart() {
        return unmodifiablePart;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ModifiableKey mk = (ModifiableKey) obj;
        return unmodifiablePart.equals(mk.getUnmodifiablePart());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return unmodifiablePart.hashCode();
    }

    public void setModifiablePart(String modifiablePart) {
        this.modifiablePart = modifiablePart;
    }

    public String getModifiablePart() {
        return modifiablePart;
    }
}
```

This class is modifiable. You can change the value of property `modifiablePart` as you like. But it can be used as well as key for a map infact **`equals` and `hashCode` doesn't change their behaviour when the modifiablePart change values.**

Comment: Could you clarify the last sentence a bit more? I think it is currently hard to understand what is meant (I can make a very educated guess, in which case it makes sense, but that should not be needed).

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling containesKey on other map and then getting value from another map. that's why you getting different result here.

```
if(hash_map.containsKey( phone))
   count_temp = hash_map_count.get( phone);
        if(count_temp == null)
```

Second, values doesn't need to be immutable in HashMap. But key need to be immutable. However map doesn't force any rule on it but if key is not immutable then you may see the unexpected behaviour in map. You can have mutable keys in map only if you make sure that the instance properties in key class which are used in hashcode() and equals(), are never changed after initialisation. 
For more details you can refer below blog.
[why-hashmap-key-should-be-immutable](https://ashokkrprajapati.blogspot.com/2019/10/why-hashmap-key-should-be-immutable-in.html)